# Fraction Cancellation Question

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I'm trying to learn some maths on my own and have come across this problem.

Find $dy/dx$:

$$ \sqrt{x + y} = \cos(y^2)$$

My working has led me to the below:

$$ -\frac{2\sqrt{x + y}}{2\sqrt{x + y}(1 + 4\sin(y^2)\sqrt{x +y})}$$

Is it legal to cancel out... $$ 2\sqrt{x + y}$$ ...from the top and the bottom?

Comment: Yes. $\,\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 0):

It is legal to cancel $2\sqrt{x + y}$ because it is being multiplied by all other terms in the denominator. If it was being added or subtracted to something, then you couldn't have canceled it out.

Comment: Hi Allan, yes, this is what I wanted to get clear in my head, actually. I had it the other way around; I thought I couldn't cancel when terms / expressions were being multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

The cancellation is legal because 
$$
\lim_{y\to\pm x} \frac{\sqrt{x + y}}{\sqrt{x + y}} = 1
$$

Did you end up with 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} =-1 -4 \color{blue}{y} \sqrt{x+y} \sin \left(y^2\right)?
$$

Comment: Hi Dantopa, I ended up with:

$$-\frac{1}}{(1 + 4sin4\sin(y^2)\sqrt{x +y})}$$

Comment: @Lucas_94: yes, it seems we differ by the factor $y$ which was why it is highlighted. At least one of us has made a mistake.

Comment: I'll be sure to review the answer to make sure I have it correct. Cheers :)